# For loop in django template returning same id for specific column

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to write an admin panel where videos can be edited, deleted and reviewed using Django. While the loop I have set up runs smoothly, it only accepts the first value as the id value in the video deletion function. I'm pretty sure I closed the for loop in the right place, I guess there's nothing wrong with it.

```
**This is my template page.**

      {% extends 'dashboard/main.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    
    {% block content  %}
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5>Edit / Show Videos</h5>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-block">
                
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'videos' %}">             
    <div id="zero-configuration_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
        <label>Search:<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Type video ID or Title" name="q" aria-controls="zero-configuration"></label>
        </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="responsive-table-model" class="display table dt-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Video ID</th>
                    <th>Video Title</th>
                    <th>Video Create Date</th>
                    <th>Video Status</th>
                    <th>Video From</th>
                    <th>Video IMG</th>
                    <th>Video Duration</th>
                    <th>Video Slug</th> 
                    <th> Action </th>      
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% autoescape off %}
    
                {% for video in videos reversed %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="tabledit-view-mode" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="tabledit-span">
                        {{ video.id }}</span></td>
                    <td>{{ video.video_title|truncatechars:25 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ video.video_create_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ video.video_status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ video.video_from }}</td>
                    <td> <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <img src="{{ video.video_img}}" alt="img" class="img-fluid animation-toggle animated" data-animate="jackInTheBox">
                    </div></td>
                    <td>{{ video.video_duration }}</td>
                    <td>{{ video.video_slug|truncatechars:25 }}</td>
                    <td>
    
    
    
                        <ul class="list-inline-item">
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                
                                
                                <a class="material-icons" href="{% url 'video' video.video_slug %}">
                                    remove_red_eye
                                    </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <a class="material-icons" href="{% url 'videosupdate' video.id %}">
                                    edit
                                    </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
                                    <a href="#myModal" class="trigger-btn" data-toggle="modal"><span class="material-icons">
                                                          delete
                                                      </span></a>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header flex-column">
                              <div class="icon-box">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i>
                                </div>              
                        <h4 class="modal-title w-100">Are you sure?</h4>    
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <p>Do you really want to delete these records? This process cannot be undone. {% url 'videosdelete' video.id %}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                                <a href="{% url 'videosdelete' video.id %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete </button></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                            
    
                    </td>
              
                </tr>
            </form>
           
              {% endfor %}
              {% endautoescape %}
    
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

**This is my urls.py**

    path ('videos-delete/<int:pk>/',VideosDelete.as_view(),name="videosdelete")

**And delete view.**

    class VideosDelete(View):
        model = Video
        def get (self, request, pk):
            videos = Video.objects.get(id=pk)
            #if request.GET.get('act') == 'delete':
            videos.delete()
            return redirect ('/dashboard/videos/')
```

[YOU CAN SEE ADMIN DASHBOARD CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVJ4n.png)

When I click the delete button to delete any video http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/videos-delete/4009/

redirects to address. 4009 is the id of the first video. My english not good, sorry for mistakes.

I tried setting up the loop in different ways, but with no results. I tried changing the URL structure and doing href="/dashboard/videos-delete/{{video.id}}", same result.

Comment: when you click, to what address does it redirect ? 
please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because you loop with the same modal id.
JS will only find your first modal and ignore the rest if the element have same id.

I can think of two solution:

Solution 1. add video.id to the Element modal id `id="myModal{{video.id}}"` and change the modal triger `href="#myModal{{video.id}}"`

Solution 2. dont include modal in loop. you just need one modal for it. You can pass the id of video using JS. (one modal and you can change the url via JS)

Comment: Your first solution worked well, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issues in the closing of tags,

- You have started the `forloop` right before the `<tr>` tag and hence it should be closed right after `</tr>`

```html
                </tr>
           {% endfor %} <!-- you shpuld have closed for here -->
```

- The  tag is opened before the `<table>`, hence it should be closed after the `</table>` only.

```
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```